# Module error Type differ in Coq

Tags: coq

I have a hard time to figure out how to write this code.

For example, I have a signature `A`, a functor `C` takes `a: A` as a parameter, to be able to use `C`, I define a module `B` implements signature `A`

```
Require Import String.
Module Type A.
  Parameter toto : string -> nat. 
End A.

Module C (Import a : A).
 ...
End C.

Module B <: A.
      Definition toto (s: string) := foo s.
End B. (* COQ error *)
```

and support I have type `foo: string -> string list-> nat.`

Then at the `End B.`, I have an error from `Coq` saying that: `signature components for label toto do not match: types differ.`

Or another way:

```
Module B.
 Definition too (s : string) := foo s.
End B.

Module Export D := C B.
```

I will get the same error at `D`

I understand the problem because I did not provide the `string list` argument in the definition of `toto`.

So my problem is I do not know how can I provide the argument `string list` in this case.

In my real code I was using `Section` and `Record` type instead of `Module`.

```
Record A : Type := mkA { too : string -> nat}.
```

Then I open a `Section`

```
Section B.
 Variable l: string list.
 Definition too (s: string) := foo s l.
 Definition A := mkA too.
End B.
```

Could you please help me to write or to understand how can I write the functor `B` in module correctly? Is there a way that I can define/declare a variable `string list` in module? Also after define in `Coq` I will extract it to `OCaml`.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can always do this:

```
Require Import String.

Parameter foo: string -> list string -> nat.

Module Type A.

  Parameter toto : string -> nat. 

End A.

Module B <: A.

  Variable (* or Parameter, or Axiom *) ls : list string.

  Definition toto (s: string) := foo s ls.

End B.
```

But to my understanding that only makes ls an axiom... Another solution is to delay the providing of ls:

```
ModuleType HasListString.

  Parameter ls : list string.

End HasListString.

Module B(LS: HasListString) : A.

  Definition toto (s: string) := foo s LS.ls.

End B.
```

This might not be what you need though. Without context, it's hard to give you better advice.

Comment: I have tried both methods. I chose the second one because the first one has a [Variable/...] it will generate an [failthwith "Axiom ..." ]after extraction. My problem was the second choice, I have no way to define the implement [ls] of signature [HasListString] in Ocaml to be able to use the function inside module [B]. [ls] is just a type in my real code.